# Workitem handlers in jbpm6

Tags: jbpm, drools-flow

Can anyone please tell me how I can to use workitem handlers in `jbpm6`. I have created a few services and I set the values of parameters for the services in the bpmn diagram. Now I want to access these parameters in my java class.

I had done this in jbpm5, it was quite simple. I just used

```
string temp= workItem.getParameter("field name");
```

But in jbpm6, it does not work.

When I use the above statement and print result on the console, I get the entered property values in jbpm5, but now I am getting "null" output on the screen.

Can anyone please help me out.

This was the closest question to My problem I found here in Stack overflow.

[Accessing KieSession from jbpm6 WorkItemHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862350/accessing-kiesession-from-jbpm6-workitemhandler)

This issue has now been resolved. Anyone else facing similar problems can refer to:

[this link](https://community.jboss.org/people/bpmn2user/blog/2013/12/29/jbpm6--custom-work-item-hello-process-example)

Answer (score 1):

The method is the same in jBPM6. I have used that in my project and it works fine. Can you check if your mappings to the work item are correct? You can't directly access a jBPM process variable that is not mapped to a work item.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I uninstalled eclipse and reinstalled it. Now it works fine. Not sure what the problem was though.